# Has anyone gotten sphinx to work with Lion?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx, osx-lion

Just curious if anyone out there has gotten Sphinx to work with Lion? If yes, how did you install it?

I seen to be running into problem after problem, cannot find anyone else who has this working yet.

Thanks!

Comment: out of curiosity, what is Lion? sphinx is basically python and I used on a plethora  of OSes without any issues...

Comment: OS X Lion - installing feels like national treasure, one problem after another

Comment: can you post the output of `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`? which version of python? Never used OSX, but I'm curios about the errors... using perhaps pastebin or snippets here.

Comment: Fredrik - I'm afraid you're confused with the Python Sphinx library for documentation - going by tags, Jason is talking about the C++ Sphinx full-text search library.

Comment: Jason: can you provide some detail on the problems you're facing trying to install it? Also: which version of Sphinx are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

Just got it to work on my Lion install.

You have to checkout the latest release from their trunk.

```
svn checkout http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sphinxsearch-read-only
```

And then follow the regular install method

```
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Thanks to [The Rails Blog](http://www.therailsblog.com/2011/07/sphinx-install-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard.html?showComment=1315946936911#c7378003062375524178) for the tip.

JP